# Row exchanges that turn each of an invertible matrix's diagonal entries nonzero

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So I need help for this problem. For a more formal statement, suppose $A\in M_n(\Bbb R)$ is non-singular, I need to prove that there exist **row exchanges** $P_1,\cdots,P_n$ such that 
$$B=P_1\cdots P_n A$$
And **each** of $B$'s diagonal entry is non-zero.

The trouble is I'm only permitted to use  row exchanges, so I don't know how to prove it constructively. If I use the column-to-column  strategy, when I'm done with the first column, namely, potentially having exchanged  the first row with another one whose first entry is nonzero so that $A_{11}$ is nonzero, then when I proceed to the second column, the will be trouble: I don't know if there is any zero entry among $A_{22},A_{32},\cdots,A_{n2}$, for instance 
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
is troublesome for this procedure.

Of course I only need to show the *existence*, but even this is difficult for me now.

Comment: Sorry. Need to add that only *row* exchanges are permissible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Laplace's formula we have $\det(A) = \sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i+1} A_{i1} \det(A^{(i,1)})$ where $A^{(i,j)}$ denotes the $(i,j)$-th minor of $A$. Because $A$ is invertible we have $\det(A) \neq 0$, so there exists some $1 \leq i \leq n$ with $A_{i1} \neq 0$ and $\det(A^{(i,1)}) \neq 0$.

Exchanging the first and $i$-th row of $A$ results in a new matrix $B$, such that the first diagonal entry of $B$ is nonzero and $B^{(1,1)}$ is invertible. Because $B^{(1,1)}$ is of size $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ we can now apply induction. (To see that $B^{(1,1)}$ is invertible simply notice that $B^{(1,1)}$ results from $A^{(i,1)}$ by exchanging the rows.)

Comment: Bravo answer ! Thanks